# Java 8 - store lambdas in List

Tags: lambda, java-8, containers, lookup-tables, binary-operators

I wonder if it's possible to store lambdas in some container, for ex. ArrayList or HashMap.
I want to change that code:

```
public enum OPCODE implements BinaryOperator<Integer> {
    MOV((x, y) -> y),
    INC((x, y) -> ++x),
    DEC((x, y) -> --x),
    ADD((x, y) -> x + y),
    SUB((x, y) -> x - y);

    private final BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator;

    OPCODE(BinaryOperator<Integer> binaryOperator) {
        this.binaryOperator = binaryOperator;
    }  

    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer integer, Integer integer2) {
        return binaryOperator.apply(integer, integer2);
    }
}
```

To something like:

```
List<BinaryOperator<Integer>> opcodes = new ArrayList<BinaryOperator<Integer>>(){
    ((x, y) -> y),
    ((x, y) -> ++x)
};
```

etc.

and use it like so:

```
opcodes[0].apply(a, b);
```

It is even possible?

Comment: As a side note, your operations `INC` and `DEC` may have not the desired effect, as Java is call by value, so modifying the parameters doesn't change any value of the caller side, so `(x, y) -> ++x` is a misleading way to formulate `(x, y) -> x+1` and likewise `(x, y) -> --x` does actually `(x, y) -> x-1`.

Comment: so really this question is just asking (1) how to use a `List` and (2) how to instantiate an `ArrayList` with given elements...

Comment: @Holger even the IDE should trigger a warning there (if OP is using one)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can certainly create such a list as:

```
List<BinaryOperator<Integer>> opcodes = Arrays.asList((x, y) -> y, (x, y) -> ++x);

// sample
int a=14,b=16;
System.out.println(opcodes.get(0).apply(a, b)); // prints 16
System.out.println(opcodes.get(1).apply(a, b)); // prints 15
```

Or redressing the way you were trying to initializing the list

```
List<BinaryOperator<Integer>> opcodes = new ArrayList<BinaryOperator<Integer>>() {{
    add((x, y) -> y);
    add((x, y) -> ++x);
    add((x, y) -> --x);
    add((x, y) -> x + y);
    add((x, y) -> x - y);
}};
```

Comment: You subclass way of writing the opcodes list makes another subclass every time you use that method, this is really inefficient

Comment: @Ferrybig Do you mean the `Arrays.asList` initialization? Didn't get you there.

Comment: Thanks, completely forgotten about Arrays.asList(). I've got suggestion to change mnemonic to clear numbers, because that way is more realistic. Well, mnemonics moved to comment then :>

Comment: No, so called double brace initialisation actually creates an anonymous subclass of `ArrayList` and then adds an instance initialiser to it. This is a hugely inefficient way of adding items to a `List`. `Arrays.asList` is significantly better.

Comment: @BoristheSpider True. Even I would have suggested to use the former approach for that reason.

Comment: @nullpointer I wonder what would happen when you would put these in a `Set`, since there is no way to override equals/hashcode for those lambdas ;)

Comment: @Eugene in this case it would be fine. Java simply uses object identity based equality for lambdas. The idea of equality of lambdas is very odd anyway - not sure what besides identity would provide a useful method of comparing them.

Comment: @BoristheSpider this was exactly my point here, the best way to handle this would be via the `enum` - which he already has in place. And while we are there, we could have done just `EnumSet.allOf` to get those into a container if needed (as I have provided in an answer)

Comment: @Eugene agree. Then `enum` is much more idiomatic. Just the phrasing of your query was a little confusing.

Answer (score 9):

In additional @nullpointer's great answer, you can also consider using a `Map` key to retain the original `OPCODE` intention of the functions, which would be lst in the array, e.g. using an `Enum` as a key:

```
public enum OPCODES {
    MOV, ADD, XOR
}
```

Which can be bootstrapped:

```
Map<OPCODES, BinaryOperator<Integer>> opcodeMap = 
  new EnumMap<OPCODES, BinaryOperator<Integer>>(OPCODES.class);
opcodeMap.put(OPCODES.ADD, (x, y)-> x + y);
opcodeMap.put(OPCODES.MOV, (x, y) -> y);
opcodeMap.put(OPCODES.XOR, (x, y) -> x ^ y);
```

And used:

```
System.out.println(opcodeMap.get(OPCODES.ADD).apply(1, 2));
System.out.println(opcodeMap.get(OPCODES.MOV).apply(1, 2));
System.out.println(opcodeMap.get(OPCODES.XOR).apply(1, 2));
```

Comment: I mean the intent of the operators would be 'Lost' by the array unless constants were defined for the ordinal indexes 0,1,2 for MOV, INC etc

Answer (score 3):

You *could* store lambdas inside a container, but the real question is why would you want to do that? Storing them in a `List` is easy, what about a `Set/Map` for example - you can't override `equals/hashcode` for lambdas - so you can't tell what would happen.

Since you already have an `Enum` there, why not use the simpler method:

```
Set<OPCODE> set = EnumSet.allOf(OPCODE.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hence you have defined your operator once you can do some thing like this:

```
List<BinaryOperator<Integer>> opcodes = new ArrayList<BinaryOperator<Integer>>() {{
    add(OPCODE.ADD);
    add(OPCODE.DEC);
}};
```

to test that in your main method:

```
opcodes.forEach(elm -> System.out.println(elm.apply(1,2)));
```

Comment: Well I believe the idea was to change it and not reuse. But still valid I would say. Though now either of the DS is left not of much use by this approach.

Comment: You can reduce instead of forEeching to achieve that result @nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put lambdas in a list or values of a map just fine. Remember that lambdas are just a fancy way of writing anonymous classes, which in turn are just a special case of the `new` operator. Put another way, `operators.add((x, y) -> x + y)` is just shorthand for

```
final BinaryOperator<Integer> ADD = new BinaryOperator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(final Integer x, final Integer y) {
        return x + y;
    }
};
operators.add(ADD);
```

By the same logic, `operatorMap.put("add", (x, y) -> x + y);` would also do exactly what you expect.

**However**, putting lambdas into a set - which includes using them as map keys - might not do what you expect. Generally, the behavior of a set depends on the definition of `equals` and `hashCode` by its element type, and the language doesn't make any guarantees for those methods beyond what's mandated by the definition of `Object`. Therefore, *the following assert can fail:*

```
final Function<Object, String> func1 = Object::toString;
final Function<Object, String> func2 = Object::toString;
assert func1.equals(func2);
```

Likewise the following:

```
final Function<Object, String> func = Object::toString;
final Set<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(func);
assert set.contains(Object::toString);
```

So, be careful putting lambdas into `Set`-based containers, including use as `Map` keys, but they can be put into `List`s and used as `Map` values just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Refining on @naomimyselfandi's answer.

You can use regular `Function` with some currying magic:

```
List<Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Integer>>> opcodes = Arrays.asList(
    (x -> y -> y),
    (x -> y -> ++x),
    (x -> y -> --x),
    (x -> y -> x + y),
    (x -> y -> x - y)
);
```

Please refer below for more details.

@Holger comment on:
[Can a java lambda have more than 1 parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872387/can-a-java-lambda-have-more-than-1-parameter)