# Pass Two Parameters In a function using lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am very new to lambdas in Java.

I have started using it as i found them quite interesting 
but i still don't know how to use them completely

I have a list of uuids and for each uuid i want to call a function which takes two parameters : first is a string and second is uuid

I am passing a constant string for each uuid

I have written a following code but its not working

```
uuids.stream()
     .map(uuid -> {"string",uuid})
     .forEach(AService::Amethod);
```

It is method which is another class AService

```
public void Amethod(String a, UUID b) {
    System.out.println(a+b.toString());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a java lambda have more than 1 parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872387/can-a-java-lambda-have-more-than-1-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda expression has a single return value, so `{"string",uuid}` doesn't work.

You could return an array using `.map(uuid -> new Object[]{"string",uuid})` but that won't be accepted by your `AService::Amethod` method reference.

In your example you can skip the `map` step:

```
uuids.stream()
     .forEach(uuid -> aservice.Amethod("string",uuid));
```

where `aservice` is the instance of `AService` class on which you wish to execute the `Amethod` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
uuids.stream().forEach(uuid -> AService.Amethod("string", uuid));
```

You *can* write something closer to your current code given a `Pair` class, but 1) you end up with more complicated code; 2) Java standard library doesn't have one built-in. Because of 2), there are quite a few utility libraries which define one. E.g. with https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html, it would be

```
uuids.stream()
        .map(uuid -> Pair.of("string",uuid))
        .forEach(pair -> AService.Amethod(pair.getLeft(), pair.getRight()));
```